# how to use ember-data with params to the api ( auth_code )

Tags: ember.js

Apologies for my english,

I am trying to use ember-data with one api and some resources of the api need the auth_code parameter.

example of my router:

```
@resource 'movies' , ->
  @route 'free'
  @route 'featured'
  @route 'favorites' , path: '/favorites'  #favorites need auth_code
  @route 'movie', path: '/:movie'
```

In MoviesFavoritesRouter i have :

```
model: ->
  App.Movie.find()
```

But how can insert the auth_code param using ember-data ??
or i have to do with jquery?

```
Ember.$.ajax(url: '/movies/favorites.json', ......, ...... )
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add custom headers to your ajax calls by just doing:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  headers: {
    "AUTH_CODE": "secret",
    "ANOTHER_HEADER": "foobar"
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: inside a route ( example : MoviesRoute ) i can insert this code ?

Comment: @user1727442, no inside your main js file, at the same level where you have `App = Ember.Application.create()`